# Django logout() crashes Python

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble with logout() while testing my project with the Django web server.  This is my logout view:

```
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return render_to_response('main.html', {})
```

When I access /logout (which calls this view) I get a popup window that says Python crashed. It doesn't give me any trace in the console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a slight problem of recursion there. `logout` is calling itself, and so on until you get a stack overflow.

Rename the view or the Django `logout` function when you import it.

Comment: use the `import ... as ...` syntax to accomplish this.

Comment: nice word play though: ".. until you get a stack overflow ...". :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even see that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer above says it all, but I find it helpful to rename external functions with some sort of unique prefix so you know where it's coming from, and because of this prefix, it will never conflict with your own functions. For example, if you're using django's logout function, you would have something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout

def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return render_to_response('main.html', {})
```